# Incorrect file permission

Tags: file, go, permissions

```
package main

import "io/ioutil"

func main() {
    greeting := "Hi there!\n"
    ioutil.WriteFile("myFile", []byte(greeting), 0666)
}
```

The problem is that when I write to file using Unix permission bits for example:

"0666"

Expected: -rw-rw-rw

Instead I get: -rw-r--r--

Please help.

Comment: Your `umask` is probably `022`, so this is the correct result.

Comment: If the file already exists, then WriteFile truncates it before writing, without changing permissions.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, umask is the reason and it was newly created file, but good to know